# Equations of motion acceleration doubt

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, differentiation, calculus

So i was going through some text today morning. Where it said

$$ a = \frac{vdv}{dx} $$

So they then went on to,

$$ vdv = adx \\ \implies \int vdv = \int adx$$

But,I am very certain **acceleration is the rate of change of velocity** which is clearly,

$$ a = \frac{dv}{dt}$$

So how do you prove.  $$ a=\frac{vdv}{dx} $$

Answer (score 2):

$$ a = \frac{dv}{dt} = \frac{dv}{dx} \frac{dx}{dt} = \frac{dv}{dx} v $$
The physics notation makes the truth of the derivation above clear because $dx/dx$ cancels. In mathematicians-style presentation of the rule, it's the chain rule for the derivative of a composite function, $v'(t(x)) =\dots$